# Convergence of difference of two divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the set of values of the real number $a$ for which 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\left(\frac1{n} − \sin \frac1{n}\right)^a$$
converges.

The root and ratio test may not be of any help here. How do we approach this problem. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: hint:  expand sin term as Taylor series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One has, as $ n \to \infty$, by a Taylor series expansion,
$$
\left(\frac1{n} − \sin \frac1{n}\right)^a=\frac1{6^a}\frac1{n^{3a}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3a+1}} \right)
$$ then one may use a [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to conclude.